# How do I identify and import only specific libraries from Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I currently have the following line in my dependency:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'

I put this in longn back when I was just starting out to code my app and now I realize that this is what is probably causing my app to bloat at about 20 MB

Is there a way to identify and specifically import only necessary services to reduce my app size? I am pretty sure there are ways to import only specific modules, but also pointers on how I can identify which modules I need will be appreciated

Comment: @SaeedDarvish - maybe you can put where the link to the actual question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app,
 For example, to include only the Google Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

with these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
```

please check this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check your project & identify which Play Services Modules are used. Then, You can selectively add the play services APIs which are necessary to your project.

For Ex : The below will be add Google Analytics and Maps modules to your app.

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
}`

Comment: is there any link to the specific modules and what they do?

Comment: Yes ! Check this https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```